# Only one option: Connect to an existing user store in the cloud

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

I want to build a web api to deploy to Azure so that I can call it from a few separate web apps to collect user input.

The users wont be logged in, but I want to ensure that only the web applications can call the api. Thus I need some kind of authentication, and I am trying to understand my options.

In Visual Studio 15.5.4 I selected New Project-> Web-> Asp.Net Core Web Application->Web API

I am wondering how ensure that only my web applications can call the web api.

I tried clicking Individual User Accounts and was surprised to find a combo box with only one option/

Have I missed a setting somewhere for there to be a combo with only one option?

[image]

If I choose Work or School Accounts instead then there is another single option combo

[image]

Comment: reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies

Comment: Which Visual Studio version is that?

Comment: I updated to show the version. VS 15.5.4

Comment: reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api

Comment: I have asked more about what I am trying to do at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48371832/how-do-i-deploy-a-restful-asp-net-core-api-to-azure-with-security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combo population for the Domain combo depends on my being logged in to Microsoft, and consequently the Active Directory domains that Azure can find associated with me.

Then using the Web Application template and work or school accounts then there is a choice of Cloud-Single Organization and Cloud-Multiple Organizations.

If I am using the Web Api template then only Cloud-Single Organization is available.